# sizeof(*this) in header only constructor implementation

Tags: c++

Whilst the 'standards' are to prefer a `sizeof(typename)`, are there any instances where the `sizeof(*this)` is *more* error-prone or somehow undesirable?

I cannot see any at the first glance, but if yes, why with a short explanation would be helpful.

Comment: cheers for the tag and edit..

Comment: The title is a noun phrase; it doesn't ask a question, and it certainly does not "say it all." What do headers have to do with anything? What are you really asking?

Comment: ok, lets nitpick. There's a question mark as a doh, question. The title is a specific context. The 'header' is a dark .h-pit that had someone, anyone, look at some code and come across the construct and wonder about its usage. Whilst a specific scenario, it's ok to ignore it and see some other perspectives. Third, the fact English is not the only language on the planet should allow for some leniency. And what I'm really asking is starting from ',' and goes beyond the italic part to the end of that paragraph. I'll edit the title but if it can be made better, please let me know again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only reason I can think of to avoid `sizeof(*this)` is that it could be misunderstood as the size of the actual object (e.g., a derived class).

Answer (score 8):

I prefer `sizeof(variable)` over `sizeof(type)` wherever possible since it's less error prone, in case your variable changes type.

Answer (score 3):

My view is that sizeof( type ) is preferable to sizeof( variable ) in order to preclude ambiguity.  The following example shows an instance of a derived class referenced through a base class pointer.  The size method returns sizeof( Derived ) so sz1 == sz3 == sz4.  The caller could reasonably expect sizeof( Base ) if they have no insight into the implementation.

```
class Base
{
  public:
    virtual size_t size( void )
    {
        return sizeof( *this ) ;
    }
  private:
    int    a ;
    double b ;
} ;

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
    virtual size_t size( void )
    {
        return sizeof( *this ) ;
    }
  private:
    long c ;
  } ;

int main( int argc , char * argv[] )
{
    Base    b ;
    Derived d ;

    size_t sz0 = sizeof( Base ) ;
    size_t sz1 = sizeof( Derived ) ;
    size_t sz2 = b.size() ;
    size_t sz3 = d.size() ;

    Base * pb = &d ;
    size_t sz4 = pb->size() ;
}
```

Comment: But then it might be more useful to know the size of the real type? - P.S The `reinterpret_cast` looks suspicious and if it does the right thing - preserving the type of `*pb` as Derived? - is entirely unneeded for upcast.

Comment: You must use sizeof( variable ) when the size of the real type is needed.  The point is that it is preferable to use sizeof( type ) to obtain the size of a specific class to avoid that effect. (You are correct that the cast is superfluous, I have edited it out)